# Is it necessary to set scoped object graphs to null in onDestroy()?

Tags: java, android, dagger

In Antonia Leiva's post about scoped object graphs (http://antonioleiva.com/dagger-3/), he writes:

"Set [the scoped graph] to null in onDestroy so that it will be freed by garbage collector as soon as possible."

```
@Override protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    activityGraph = null;
}
```

To clarify, `activityGraph` is a scoped graph creating by calling `plus` on the application object graph.

Is it necessary to set `activityGraph` to null, or will it be garbage collected as soon as the class it injects no longer exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necessary? No.

When `onDestroy` is called the reference to the Activity will soon be freed and be made available for CG. The GC will see that the Activity is the only reference to the scoped graph and both will be marked for collection.

Setting it to `null` is not really bad either. You ensure no one can use the graph after destroy under punishment of NPE. If someone accidentally leaks the Activity reference the graph will be made available for GC. Optimizing for reference leaking isn't the best practice, however, since the app will eventually OOM anyway. In fact, not setting the graph to `null` will help it OOM faster forcing you to identify the problem!

Comment: Thanks! I was worried that the app object graph kept a reference to the scoped object graph, but it appears this is not the case.

Comment: Correct (it does not keep a reference). The child has a reference to the parent in this case.

Comment: Ok this is fine. But the question is: Do we really need to have it as a class field? If we only need to inject some fields, can't we just make it local inside the method? In this case we shouldn't have any problem regarding memory leaks. Am I wrong?